# Prononciation du "d" final dans le mot quand

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

J'entends de plus en plus, dans les discours de politiciens français notamment, qu'ils prononcent toujours le d final du mot quand, alors que selon les règles phonétiques, il ne se prononce que quand il est suivi d'un voyelle. Est-ce que c'est un nouveau phénomène qui devient de plus en plus courant ? D'abord j'ai pensé que c’était le son d'hésitation 'eu' ajouté a quand, mais je constate cet habitude même avec des personnes au debit très vite, quand il y a pas de pause entre quand et le mot qui suit.

Comment: Est-ce que vous avez un exemple sur youtube?

Comment: J'ai remarque cela dans deux intervues de jean luc melenchon. mais comme ils sont longs ce ne serait pas utile de vous donner les liens je pense

Comment: @Frank Je viens d'ajouter à ma réponse un exemple tout récent de ce *Kant* présidentiel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pour compléter la réponse de Destal :

Le « d » final de « quand » n'est jamais prononcé « d » mais il est prononcé « t » quand « quand » est suivi d'un mot commençant par une voyelle et que la liaison est faite.

Ex: « quand il vient » /kɑ̃tilvjɛ̃/ . L'explication tient à l'ancien français où « quand » s'écrivait et se prononçais « quant », comme « grand → grant ».

Quand « quand » est suivi d'un mot commençant par une consonne, il n'y a normalement pas de liaison mais, si une pause suit « quand », un [t] se fait parfois entendre. Cette pause peut être notée par un « heu » mais souvent il n'y a pas vraiment de « heu », le « t » termine simplement la syllabe précédente.

Les instituteurs faisaient parfois ce style de liaisons forcées lors de dictées, voire des liaisons inventées comme les fameux « moutonss » de Topaze.

Plus récemment, Jacques Chirac était lui aussi très connu pour marquer des pauses avant les liaisons.

[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais)

> La maîtrise et le dosage des liaisons (mais sans lecture obligatoire des e « caducs ») participe également de l'art oratoire : il s'agit, de fait, d'un des « éléments phonostylistiques les plus facilement décelables de la prononciation » (P. Léon). Les professionnels de la parole publique tantôt suppriment un fort pourcentage de liaisons facultatives (Bernard Pivot), tantôt les réalisent toutes ou encore en modulent le pourcentage en fonction du public visé, comme le faisait le général de Gaulle. **Dans ce cadre se développe un emploi étranger à l'oral courant même soutenu, mais fréquent dans les allocutions radiodiffusées et télévisuelles de certains hommes politiques** (Jacques Chirac, par exemple, est coutumier du fait) : il consiste à prononcer automatiquement certaines liaisons indépendamment du mot suivant, tout en introduisant une pause (disjonction ou voyelle d'hésitation notée traditionnellement euh) à la suite de la consonne de liaison. Par exemple : ils ont entendu est normalement prononcé [ilz‿ ɔ̃ ɑ̃tɑ̃dy] ou, plus soutenu, [ilz‿ ɔ̃t‿ ɑ̃tɑ̃dy] ; un locuteur pratiquant la prononciation en question dira [ilz‿ ɔ̃t | ɑ̃tɑ̃dy] ([|] représente une pause ; « ils ont'… entendu ») [ilz‿ ɔ̃təː(ːːː) ɑ̃tɑ̃dy] (« ils ont euh… entendu »). **On peut même entendre ils ont décidé prononcé [ilz‿ ɔ̃t | deside]** (« ils ont'… décidé ») ou [ilz‿ ɔ̃təː(ːːː) deside] (« ils ont euh… décidé »). Dans le premier cas, une pause entre deux mots reliés de manière si forte produit un effet étrange ; quant au second cas, il partage avec le pataquès le fait que la consonne est non motivée.

(c'est moi qui souligne)

Encore plus récemment, [Emmanuel Macron, le 23 mars 2023.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ah-_JmvULJc&t=216s)  :

> 3 min 41 s : *Quan**T** le Brésil a vécu ce qu'il a vécu, Quan**T** vous avez eu l'extrême violence en Allemagne, aux Pays-Bas ou parfois par le passé chez nous [...]*

Comment: Ah oui! Je me souviens maintenant que mon instituteur faisait ça pour les dictées à l'école primaire!

Comment: Cette reponse a vraiment repondu a ma question et merci pour le lien du page Wikipedia.

Comment: Bizarre... la langue change en permanence.

Comment: @Frank C'est un signe de bonne santé, elle est encore vivante !  :-)

Answer (score 6):

Si j'ai bien compris ce dont tu parles, il s'agit en effet d'un style oral très politique.

Il n'est possible que lorsque la phrase est prononcée lentement, comme s'il y avait le "euh" d'hésitation mais qu'il n'était pas dit. "Ecoutez madame. Quand... vous avez... 5000 personnes dans la rue...". Si la phrase était prononcée à vitesse normale, je pense que ça sonnerait bizarrement.

C'est comme si on sous-entendait le "euh" ou qu'on avait failli le dire, mais qu'on s'était ravisé au dernier moment, mais trop tard : la liaison est faite.

Par pure supposition, je dirais que c'est pour garder ce côté "parler très lent et ponctué" mais sans dire le "euh" qui n'est pas joli, à fortiori dans un discours politique.

Comment: Merci, c'est ce que je pensais aussi. Donc selon vous si j'ai bien compris, quand on parle normalement, le 'd' ne sera pas prononce a l'exception des hommes politiques. Pour ajouter, chez mes amis francais j'ai aussi remarque cette habitude de dire quand(euh)

Comment: Pas seulement les politiques mais toute personne voulant donner un ton un peu solennel à son discours (mais on pourrait très bien en rire, car c'est un effet superficiel). Le "euh" est courant en français oral, s'il arrive après un "quand", la liaison est souvent faite.

Answer (score 1):

Cette prononciation du mot "quand" n'est à ma connaissance qu'utilisée en France ou par les Français. Possiblement plus dans les discours politiques, mais j'en entends également de la part de Français immigrants ou en visite qui n'ont aucun lien avec la politique.

Il est important de noter qu'il y a un mot qui se prononce avec un t, il s'agit de "quant", et a une tout autre signification. Il est utilisé dans le cas de "quant à lui", ou "quant à moi, on ne devrait pas prononcer le d comme un t".

Pour répondre à la question:

> Est-ce que c'est un nouveau phénomène qui devient de plus en plus courant ?

Ici au Québec, non, j'ignore ce qui se passe en France, mais considérant qu'il y a un mot qui se prononce avec un t et qu'il a un autre sens, il est permis de croire (et même d'espérer) que cette pratique va lentement disparaître.

Comment: Il y a peu de chance que disparaisse de sitôt la pratique de prononcer comme un **t** le **d** final de l'héritier français du *quando* latin car elle existe depuis au moins le XIIe siècle. Le « d » final de « quand » n'a qu'une valeur étymologique et n'a donc pas vocation à être prononcé. Si la liaison est faite, c'est toujours un « t » qui est prononcé. Le « t » de « quant » se prononce lui toujours car ce mot n'existe que lorsqu'il est suivi de « à » et la liaison y est obligatoire, contrairement à « quand » ou la liaison est facultative.

Comment: C'est où, _par ici_? Au Québec?

Comment: oui, au Québec.

Answer (score 0):

Moi aussi, j'avais fait cette observation. Si vous avez un peu de temps, je vous conseille de lire cet article scientifique excellent : http://ycmorin.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/1988_liaison_devant_consonne_quand_vingt.pdf
Cordialement