# Prononciation du s final en "ils/elles" même sans liaison

Tags: prononciation, apprentissage

Dans une école primaire (classe CE1), on m'a dit que lorsque les écoliers pratiquent la conjugaison, l'institutrice a dit de prononcer le s final de "ils/elles".

Par exemple :

> il**S** parlent/ elle**S** parlent

Je pense que l'institutrice veut les aider à faire la différence avec il/elle (singulier). Est-ce une pratique récente ? Est-elle répandue ?

Comment: Tu es sûr ? Ce n'étaient pas plutôt les liaisons avec les voyelles ?

Comment: From anecdotal experience, North American Anglophone schools without immersion programs, this shortcut is sometimes taken to draw a student's attention to the plural. The result is probably just confusion about liaison and even conjugation (what do you mean I have to listen to the verb ending?). I know nothing about Francophone schooling. I'm interested in hearing more about Mathieu's experience, though.

Comment: Je l'ai déjà entendu faire, en effet. Quant à discuter de si cela relève d'une bonne pratique pédagogique ne relève pas de French Language et donc je m'abstiendrai ! Enfin j'ajoute juste que d'autres enseignants font dire « ils/elles au pluriel », la notion de pluriel étant déjà bien introduite en CE 1.

Comment: Jamais entendu de mon côté. Ça se pronounce comment, /ɛləs/, /ɛls/, /ɛlz/?

Comment: @Eauquidort : Elle prononce ɛls.

Comment: Si c'est vraiment le cas, je vois déjà arriver les problèmes de confusion entre « elleS obtiennent » et « elle(s) s'obtient/nent »…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Comme j'ai dit c'était pour une conjugaison typique : ilS parlent/ elleS parlent.

Comment: @Laure Oui, je l'avais évoqué dans une question un peu similaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25095/prononciation-du-d-final-dans-le-mot-quand/25108#25108 mais à propos d'un phénomène beaucoup plus courant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En effet, on prononce parfois le s pour éviter une ambiguïté. "Ils faisaient" par exemple peut être confondu avec "il faisait". Quand on se rend compte du risque de confusion on peut répéter en prononçant le s.

Comment: Tu parles de l'apprentissage des conjugaisons ou d'autre chose ?

Comment: Les deux. Hier j'ai entendu un adulte dire "ilS/elleS" à un enfant en conjuguant un verbe à toutes les personnes. Mais c'est pertinent dès qu'il existe une ambiguïté.

Comment: Pourquoi la vote négative ?

Comment: Probablement parce que ça ne correspond pas à l'expérience de la personne qui a *moinssé*, parce que la réponse ne fournit pas de références ou de précision sur qui est *on*, et parce que ce serait (ou c'est, si elle est avérée) une pratique pédagogique affligeante...